# component re-render always while hover on sidebar how can i optimize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a sidebar in the web app and when the cursor hovers it sidebar expands and when the cursor leaves it collapses.
I attach my console screenshot in 15sec re-render trigger a lot.
But while hovering all parts of the sidebar state continue to change.
how can I stop continuing re-rendering of components?
Here is the code and you can see it in the console also. [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wind-4mgtzj?file=/src/App.js)

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    sidebarClass: ''
  });

  const onHandleMouseOver = () => {
    setState(pre => ({
      ...pre,
      sidebarClass: 'expend'
    }))
  }
  const onHandleMouseLeave = () => {
    setState(pre => ({
      ...pre,
      sidebarClass: 'collapse'
    }))
  }

  console.log('component re-render')

  return (
    <div 
    onMouseOver={onHandleMouseOver}
    onMouseLeave={onHandleMouseLeave}

    className={`App ${state.sidebarClass}`}
    >
      
    </div>
  );
```

[image: error]

Comment: I don't see the behavior you're describing in your sandbox example. The sidebar only seems to re-render when the mouse enters or leaves the area, as expected.

Comment: I really don't know about code sandbox but in my browser console it continue to render but I fixed it with CSS only